# Magento2 - Custom Payment Method - standard approach to show dynamic data on payment method

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, knockoutjs

What is the best way to show dynamic data (i-e pending balance or something) on payment method at checkout page ?

Here is the screenshot for further reference.

[image]

USD 1000 is the dynamic value which i can retrieve from any block or any controller through ajax call, but i am not really sure if i have to use ajax call on checkout page or use knockout js or magento2 UI functionlity to do that.